# Bayes spam filtering for two word

Tags: probability-theory

the Baysian spam filter has been trained using 1 million emails, exactly half of which are spams.  Suppose for simplicity the spam filter only focus on two words: 'urgent' and 'account'  Of the spams, 200 thousand of them contain the word 'urgent,' and 100 thousand of them contain the word 'account.'  Of the non-spam emails, 1 thousand of them contain the word 'urgent' and 2 thousand of them contain the word 'account.'  Suppose now we apply this spam filter to new emails.  Answer the following two questions.

a) If a new email contains both 'urgent' and 'account,' what is the probability that it is a spam?

b) If a new email contains the word 'account' but not the word 'urgent,' what is the probability that it is a spam?

I consider w1 = "urgent" and w2 = "account" and based on these :

P(w1|spam) = 2/5
P(w2|spam) = 1/5
P(w1|no-spam) = 1/500
P(w2|no-spam) = 1/250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Baysian spam filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476941/baysian-spam-filter)

Comment: Please do not repost your question after a negative reception (and **certainly** not less than an hour after posting it). Regardless, both of your questions are off-topic here: Please [edit] the questions to include your own thoughts and efforts. This is not a do-my-homework site. (Also, it's "Bayesian.")